# How can I parse very nested json by newton in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization

How can I access second item in execution-results: " **"value": 1,**" I can not do that.How can I get second value?

```
  JObject jo = JObject.Parse(Resource1.samplejson);
        var valueQuery = jo.SelectTokens("results[*].value").Any();
```

```
{{
  "type": "SUCCESS",
  "msg": "Container test successfully called.",
  "result": {
    "execution-results": {
      "results": [
        {
          "value": {
            "com.myteam.test.Pricing": {
              "a": 0.196100271932827,
               "b": 7,
               "c": 0.012,

            }
          },
          "key": "mymodel"
        },
        {
          "value": 1,
          "key": ""
        }
      ],
      "facts": [
        {
          "value": {
            "org.test.core.common.DefaultFactHandle": {
              "external-form": "0:598:701211836:701211836:1164:DEFAULT:NON_TRAIT:com.myteam.x.mymodel"
            }
          },
          "key": "mymodel"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}}
```

Comment: Is this a valid Json ? the starting `{{` and the  "c": 0.012**,**  looked wrong for me. Once you have map the valid Json you can simply: `BaseClass.ExecutionResults.results.Skip(1).Take(1)`. But The issue is that result has a property value that is either an object or an int ..

Comment: I am always puzzle with those Json(multiple type same name property, invalid name): What could be the original Object that gave those Json ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this for inner object you will get true if data exists in inner property and use $. for inner and $.. for inner of inner and so on....

```
var valueQuery = jo.SelectTokens("$..results[*].value").Any();
if(valueQuery){
//Write your logic to retrieve data from object 
}
```

and retrieve values from data

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but is this what you wanted

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(json);

            Console.WriteLine(jo["result"]["execution-results"]["results"][1]["value"].Value<int>());

            dynamic jod = jo;

            Console.WriteLine(jod.result["execution-results"].results[1].value);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NewtonSoft, you can do the following:

```
dynamic data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Resource1.samplejson);
string myValue = data.result.execution-results.results[1].value
```

That's assuming that your data structure never changes.

Otherwise you can do the following and navigate down to the value you need while checking that the entries that you expected are actually in the json

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>();
if (values.ContainsKey("result") == true) 
{
// ... Go futher down
}
```